# Bind dynamic properties in WPF: bind to DynamicObject or Dictionary, or else?

Tags: c#, wpf, dynamic, mvvm, binding

I am working on a WPF application with database, entity framework 4.

One of the function is like the TFS workitem submit. Besides the core fields, the user is allowed to add some extra fields and save. The main problem is binding the extra fields to the UI. Just a UI with the least function is enough: some core fields, and stackpanel or itemscontrol or something similar that can show the extra fields.

I currently have two main ideas:

1. the DynamicObject, the properties can be created at runtime, but I
   don't know yet how to bind them to the UI(I need your solution
   please)?
2. bind a dictionary to itemscontrol(But is it good style of binding? especially when I want some MVVM style， or when I need different datatemplates for different property types?)

Since I'm quite newbie to programming, I don't know even which of the above will finally work. I am just imaging and asking question before finally trying them out. Could you suggest a way that is simplest?

Comment: This is a subjective question that depends on user's opinions... as such, it is off topic for Stack Overflow and it will almost certainly be deleted unless you edit it to make it less *opinion based*.

Comment: @Sheridan thanks, I edited, do you think it is right now?

Comment: Really, this website is generally for questions that involve a particular programming problem that a user is currently facing... it's really not suited to *which way should I go* and *which is better* type questions. However, as you have made an effort to make your question less opinion based, I'd like to think that the Stack Overflow community will give you a break and not close your question.

Comment: Odd, seems like you're already there.  Most DynamicObject implementations are backed by a dictionary, so in the UI you just bind as if the property exists, then in the DynamicObject index into your dictionary by the property name.  The Aristocrats.

Comment: @Will the property names are set at runtime, so how to "as if the property exists"? What are the binding paths?

Comment: @LeiYang: I have a dynamic object which, at runtime, is asked to set/get a property value.  I am given the name of the property and the value of the property.  I store that value under that property name.  If somebody asks for the value of a property, I am given the name and go look for the value indexed under the name.  From the outside it looks like any other property set/get operation.  Therefore the binding paths are exactly the same as if the property was a Plain Old CLR Object Property.  It cannot be more trivial than that.  Try it for yourself FFS.

Comment: @Will I'm mainly concerned with binding to UI, but you seem to just mentioned the values. Does your binding similiar to that of @Sheridan?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In WPF, we work with *data elements*, rather than *UI elements*. By this, I mean that your users will add *data* that relates to these new properties. Your job is to display this data, possibly for editing purposes even. In this respect, it is no different to any other view. Typically, we display the data by declaring `DataTemplate`s.

In your case, assuming that you have `string` properties that a user has added, they could be stored in a class similar to this:

```
public class CustomData // Implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface here
{
    public string Label { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Then to display it as editable data, you just need to define the correct `DataTemplate`:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="Template" DataType="{x:Type DataTypes:CustomData}">
    <Grid Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="Label" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Label}" />
        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Value}" />
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

This `DataTemplate` would display your data items with their `Label` and `Value` properties data bound to the controls in the `Grid`. The `Grid.IsSharedSizeScope` and `SharedSizeGroup` properties will ensure that all of the controls line up together in a nice straight line.

Finally, data bind a collection of items of this type to an `ItemsControl.ItemsSource` property to display them:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding YourCustomDataCollection}" />
```

You could even `Style` the `ListBox` so that it doesn't look like a `ListBox`, so that your custom data controls just look like a column of normal controls.

Comment: Thanks for writing so much words, I'll try it asap!